# Why are my equations numbered?

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath, alignment

In my maths document on Overleaf, I am using the `amsmath` package, and whenever I use
`\begin{equation}  \begin{split}`
and
`\end{split} \end{equation}`
to split equations and to have a new equality sign per line I always get the equations being numbered on the right hand side of the page. Any idea why?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, the `equation` environment provides single numbering; on the other hand, `equation*` doesn't. If you want all lines numbered, you need to use `align`.

Comment: @egreg   So if I write `\begin{equation*}` every time instead then wil it have no numbering?

Comment: yes or `\[...\]` which is the same thing (but defined in latex itself rather than amsmath) as egreg says, usually it is simpler to use `\begin{align*}` than `\begin{equation*}\begin{split}`

Comment: @A-levelStudent Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: @egreg thanks for the confirmation, I think it's amazing that you have helped so many people on this site...over 50M reached!!!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the comment, I think you have helped me out on every single one of my questions...I really appreciate it, and I think it's incredibly kind of you to devote so much time to helping people, thank you so much.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments.

Comment: @Marijn Ok. Are questions considered off-topic if they are solved in comments?

Comment: @A-levelStudent not really, your question is of course on-topic. There is a bit of a backstory here in how this kind of comments are handled - 'officially' such a comment should either be converted into an answer which can then be voted upon, or a proper duplicate question should be found to close this question against. However here on TeX.SE we usually close such a question instead if the answer is in comments. Historically the off-topic reason was (ab)used for this purpose, currently that is no longer necessary because you can now close using a 'community guideline' reason,

Comment: but out of habit I used off-topic.

Comment: @Marijn OK, thanks for the explanation, no worries :)